# Snake - slow response time on key press

Tags: java, javafx

I've made a snake game (by trying to follow a youtuber's code), and the direction is controlled by WASD. However, when i press one of the keys, nothing happens. If i hold it down, it changes direction, but there's a huge delay, probably more than a second. How do i fix this? I've looked over my code and compared it to the youtube code i followed several times, but still can't seem to see what the problem is. This is the first time i've made a game, so i'm very new to this.

This is the video i tried to follow, if that helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK6l1uVlunc

```
package app;


import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage; // Kontrollerer tittel, ikon, synlighet, størrelse, og dekorasjoner
import javafx.util.Duration;



public class App extends Application {

    public enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT;
    }

    public static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 40;
    public static final int APP_W = 20 * BLOCK_SIZE;
    public static final int APP_H = 15 * BLOCK_SIZE;

    public int score = 0;
    public int highScore = 0;

    private Direction direction = Direction.RIGHT; // Default spawn-bevegelse: til høyre
    private boolean moved = false; 
    private boolean running = false; // Applikasjonen kjører

    private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    private ObservableList<Node> snake;

    private Parent createContent() {

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(APP_W, APP_H);

        Group snakeBody = new Group();
        snake = snakeBody.getChildren();    

        Rectangle food = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        food.setFill(Color.RED);
        food.setTranslateX((int)(Math.random() * (APP_W - BLOCK_SIZE)) / BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE);
        food.setTranslateY((int)(Math.random() * (APP_H - BLOCK_SIZE)) / BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE);

        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), event -> {
            if (!running)
                return;
            boolean toRemove = snake.size() > 1;

            Node tail = toRemove ? snake.remove(snake.size()-1) : snake.get(0);

            double tailX = tail.getTranslateX();
            double tailY = tail.getTranslateY();

            switch (direction) {
                case UP: 
                    tail.setTranslateX(snake.get(0).getTranslateX());
                    tail.setTranslateY(snake.get(0).getTranslateY() - BLOCK_SIZE);
                    break;
                case DOWN: 
                    tail.setTranslateX(snake.get(0).getTranslateX());
                    tail.setTranslateY(snake.get(0).getTranslateY() + BLOCK_SIZE);
                    break;
                case RIGHT: 
                    tail.setTranslateX(snake.get(0).getTranslateX() + BLOCK_SIZE);
                    tail.setTranslateY(snake.get(0).getTranslateY());
                    break;
                case LEFT: 
                    tail.setTranslateX(snake.get(0).getTranslateX() - BLOCK_SIZE);
                    tail.setTranslateY(snake.get(0).getTranslateY());
                    break;
            }

            moved = true;

            if (toRemove)
                snake.add(0, tail);

            // Kollisjonsdeteksjon

            // Krasjer i seg selv
            for (Node rect : snake) {
                if (rect != tail && tail.getTranslateX() == rect.getTranslateX() && tail.getTranslateY() == rect.getTranslateY()) {
                    restartGame();
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Krasjer i kant
            if (tail.getTranslateX() < 0 || tail.getTranslateX() >= APP_W || tail.getTranslateY() < 0 || tail.getTranslateY() >= APP_H) {
                restartGame();
            }

            // Legg til mat
            if (tail.getTranslateX() == food.getTranslateX() && tail.getTranslateY() == food.getTranslateY()) {
                food.setTranslateX((int)(Math.random() * (APP_W - BLOCK_SIZE)) / BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE);
                food.setTranslateY((int)(Math.random() * (APP_H - BLOCK_SIZE)) / BLOCK_SIZE * BLOCK_SIZE);

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
                rect.setTranslateX(tailX);
                rect.setTranslateY(tailY);
                snake.add(rect);
            }



        });

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        root.getChildren().addAll(food, snakeBody);

        return root;
    }

    private void restartGame() {
        stopGame();
        startGame();
    }

    private void stopGame() {
        running = false;
        timeline.stop();
        snake.clear();
    }

    private void startGame() {
        direction = Direction.RIGHT;
        Rectangle head = new Rectangle(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
        snake.add(head);
        timeline.play();
        running = true;
    }





    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//      primaryStage.setTitle("My Application");
//      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource("App.fxml"))));
//      primaryStage.show();    

        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (!moved)

            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    if (direction != Direction.DOWN)
                        direction = Direction.UP;
                    break;

                case S:
                    if (direction != Direction.UP)
                        direction = Direction.DOWN;
                    break;
                case A:
                    if (direction != Direction.RIGHT)
                        direction = Direction.LEFT;
                    break;
                case D:
                    if (direction != Direction.LEFT)
                        direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                    break;
            default:
                break;

            }
            moved = false;
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Snake");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        startGame();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        App.launch(args); // Kaller init(), start() og så stop()
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple example where your program responds to a keypress by, say, outputting to the console?

Comment: That was a good suggestion. I tried it now, and the same thing happened - no output if i press it, but it outputs with delay if i hold it down.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. I found a function called setOnKeyTyped() and replaced the setOnKeyPress() function with that, but then it doesn't seem like it responds to any key press at all.

Comment: I think i just found what i did wrong: i didn't write anything after if (!moved), i should have written return; after that. Works on key press now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the difference from your code to the one from the tutorial.

```
if (!moved)
     return;

switch (event.getCode()) {
     .
     .
     .
}
moved = false;
```

In your code the return statement after the if(!moved) is missing. I tried to add it in my code and afterwards it works for me.

Hopefully that solves your Problem.
Cheers Malte

Comment: Yup i found out a couple of minutes ago, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that everytime the `KeyFrame` is triggered, you reset the `moved` flag. This requires the user to trigger at least 2 `KEY_PRESSED` events between frames to get the direction to change.

Assuming you want to prevent the user from changing the direction before the first frame, you should remove the negation in the `if` condition. (Depending on what you're trying to achieve with the flag, you may need a different fix).

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (moved) {

        switch (event.getCode()) {
        case W:
            if (direction != Direction.DOWN)
                direction = Direction.UP;
            break;

        case S:
            if (direction != Direction.UP)
                direction = Direction.DOWN;
            break;
        case A:
            if (direction != Direction.RIGHT)
                direction = Direction.LEFT;
            break;
        case D:
            if (direction != Direction.LEFT)
                direction = Direction.RIGHT;
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    }
});
```

---

Also there are a few things you could improve about the code by using a `Map` and adding properties to the `Direction` enum.

```
public enum Direction {
    UP(0, -1), RIGHT(1, 0), DOWN(0, 1), LEFT(-1, 0);

    private final int dx;
    private final int dy;

    private Direction(int dx, int dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    /**
     * Tests, if 2 directions are parallel (i.e. both either on the x or the y axis).<br>
     * Note: Depends on the order of the enum constants
     * @param other the direction to compare with
     * @return true, if the directions are parallel, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isParallel(Direction other) {
        return ((ordinal() - other.ordinal()) & 1) == 0;
    }
}
```

In the `KeyFrame`

```
...
double tailX = tail.getTranslateX();
double tailY = tail.getTranslateY();

Node head = snake.get(0);
tail.setTranslateX(head.getTranslateX() + BLOCK_SIZE * direction.dx);
tail.setTranslateY(head.getTranslateY() + BLOCK_SIZE * direction.dy);

moved = true;
...
```

```
final Map<KeyCode, Direction> keyMapping = new EnumMap<>(KeyCode.class);
keyMapping.put(KeyCode.W, Direction.UP);
keyMapping.put(KeyCode.S, Direction.DOWN);
keyMapping.put(KeyCode.A, Direction.LEFT);
keyMapping.put(KeyCode.D, Direction.RIGHT);

Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (moved) {
        Direction newDirection = keyMapping.get(event.getCode());
        if (newDirection != null && !direction.isParallel(newDirection)) {
            direction = newDirection;
        }
    }

});
```